# Excel -Dynamic column headers as indirect drop-down list data validation source

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a dropdown list with indirect reference to column headers which works good, but once my table expands with new columns, the dropdownlist isn't updated with new column headers accordingly.

Is it possible to update to achieve for column headers like it is achievable for column rows?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't convert your source range to an Excel Table? That way, an indirect reference to the header row will always capture additional columns. And what do you mean by "*Is it possible to update to achieve for column headers like it is achievable for column rows?*"

Comment: Try to use the Table for the list in Excel. You can provide a sample about the problem here.

Comment: Please try to use Offset and counta functions to [create a dynamic drop down list in Excel](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/excel-drop-down-list/).

Answer (score 0):

my bad i didn't laydown the problem correctly, my table is as follows, it reprents available vrfs for each tenant

|tn-common| tn-mgmt | tn-infra |
|:------- |:-------:| --------:|
| vrf-1  | vrf-7    | vrf-5    |
| vrf-2  | vrf-8    | vrf-6    |
to allow my vrf dropdown list to contain a selected tenant vrfs, i need to create namespaces for each column header:e.g: common(vrf-1,vrf2); mgmt(vrf-7,vrf-8), thats Ok, but the problem is when my table got updated with new column, say tn-production, i need to manually create the name space tn-production(vrfx,vrfy) to make it possible for child dropdownlist(vrfs) to display the new tenant info.
is there a way to automate namesapace extension in my case.
Thank you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello,can i ask a question, is it possible to dynamically create namespaces  when excel table table grows horizontally .for example, i have 2 columns in my table (product,label), each column got its namespace to use in dropdownlist: product(product1,product2) and label(label1,label2), my table updates from source which can resize the table, for example adding a third coloumn called color(blue,red), the name space is n't created automatically for the new column in the table, is it possible to do it automagically?, thank you